# How to add new row in dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframe that look like:

df1:

```
      V1      V2     V3     V4
rs200140498 chr1    861315  GG
rs371217242 chr1    861329  AA
rs200686669 chr1    861349  CC
rs370046315 chr1    861357  CC
rs374110379 chr1    861521  GG
rs74045401  chr1    861530  GG
rs377418023 chr1    865394  CC
rs79027658  chr1    865438  CC
rs202189913 chr1    865488  AA
rs370992396 chr1    865543  GG
```

and df2:

```
      V1      V2     V3     V4
rs200140498 chr1    861315  GG
rs200686669 chr1    861349  CC
rs370046315 chr1    861357  CC
rs74045401  chr1    861530  GG
rs377418023 chr1    865394  CC
rs202189913 chr1    865488  AA
rs370992396 chr1    865543  GG
```

And I want to compare its and get new data frame:

```
          V1      V2     V3     V4
 rs200140498    chr1    861315  GG
 rs371217242    chr1    861329  --
 rs200686669    chr1    861349  CC
 rs370046315    chr1    861357  CC
 rs374110379    chr1    861521  --
 rs74045401     chr1    861530  GG
 rs377418023    chr1    865394  CC
 rs79027658     chr1    865438  --
 rs202189913    chr1    865488  AA
 rs370992396    chr1    865543  GG
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
library(dplyr) #you need to install and load the dplyr package

df3 <- left_join(df1,df2, by=c("V1", "V2", "V3"))
df3 <- df3[,-4]
View(df3)
```

Also, if you need only the differences, then I recommend the `anti_join` function:

```
df4 <- anti_join(df1,df2, by=c("V1", "V2", "V3"))
View(df4)
```

And if you need `--` instead of `NA` values, then use this:

```
df3$V4.y <- replace(df3$V4.y, is.na(df3$V4.y), "--")
```